# How to update multiple columns in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multiple-columns

hi am trying to update multiple column , how can i? the first column is shoe1, wanna add another column but cant

```
// shoe1
$query = "SELECT shoe_id, shoes_image, 
         shoes FROM " . $DBPrefix . "shoes";

$params[] = array(':shoe_id', floor($time_passed), 'int');
$db->query($query, $params);

$TPL_shoe1_list = '<select name="shoe1">' . "\n";

while ($row = $db->fetch())
{
    $selected = ($row['shoes'] == $shoe1) ? 'selected="true"' : '';
    $TPL_shoe1_list .= "\t" . '<option value="' . $row['shoes'] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $row['shoes'] .'</option>' . "\n";
}

$TPL_shoe1_list .= '</select>' . "\n";
```

Comment: hi thanks for d reply is the a way u can make it a bit easier for me, like using d code above and adding the second column for me which is (shoe2) thanks

Answer (score 1):

In General the sql syntax is

```
UPDATE table-name 
   SET column-name = value, column-name = value, ...
 WHERE condition
```

Example:

```
UPDATE Supplier
   SET City = 'Oslo', Phone = '(0)1-953530', Fax = '(0)1-953555'
 WHERE Id = 15
```

Comment: hi thanks for d reply is the a way u can make it a bit easier for me, like using d code above and adding the second column for me which is (shoe2) thanks